# Having problems with consecutive sums in C

Tags: c, sum, printf

I'm beginner in C and I am having problems when i try to sum a serie of prime numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int n, div, prime, i, x;
    float serie;
    serie = 0;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    int list[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // creates a sequence from 1 to n
        list[i] = i + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){ // check if a number is prime
        div = 2;
        prime = 1;
        while (div < list[i]) {
            if (list[i] % div == 0) {
                prime = 0;
            }
            div = div + 1;
        }
        if (prime == 1) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                serie = serie - (1 / list[i]);
            } else {
                serie = serie + (1 / list[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%f", serie);

    return 0;
}
```

No matter what number I put in n, the result of sum is always 0.000000.
What must I do?

Comment: Why your code tries to calculate prime numbers instead of partial sums?

Comment: `1 / list[i]` will always be zero for `i` > 0. You probably want to do this instead `1.0 / (float) list[i]`

Comment: Because I have to do something like this: serie = 1/2 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/N + ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason why `serie` is 0.0, is because `list[i]` is an integer. cast it to float first, in your substraction/addition from `serie`:

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
    serie = serie - (1 / (float)list[i]);
} else {
    serie = serie + (1 / (float)list[i]);
}
```

Comment: Now  `serie`  is  -1.0 no matter what I do.

Comment: I haven't checked your algorithm in terms of what 'you intend it' to do. but for example when I enter `100` I get the output `-0.802817`

Answer (score 1):

The code here:

```
        if (prime == 1) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                serie = serie - (1 / list[i]);
            } else {
                serie = serie + (1 / list[i]);
            }
        }
```

Is executing integer division, which is always going to result in the (1/list[i]) part evaluating to 0. In order to execute the calculation, you must use floating point arithmetic, which you can do by using a float cast, or a floating point literal (.f suffix) instead of an integer:

```
        if (prime == 1) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                serie = serie - (1.f / list[i]);
            } else {
                serie = serie + (1.f / list[i]);
            }
        }
```